# Обращение к БД postgre по таймауту

Tags: база-данных, node.js, postgresql

```
var timer = setTimeout(function tick(){
  connectionToHouse.query('SELECT ....', (err,rows,fields)=>{
    if (!err){
      if(rows[0]['...'] == 1){
       connectToUsersHouse.query("UPDATE ...",(err,result)=>{
          if(!err){

          }
        });
```

Здравствуйте, я с помощью nodejs создаю коннект к БД. Потом через каждую секунду обращаюсь к БД и обновляю данные в таблицах в зависимости от условий. То есть каждую секунду происходит обновление большого числа ячеек в таблицы БД. Насколько плохо это? Если количество соединений превысит 5000 или больше,
что может произойти? Или это не так критично?

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно обновлять много данных - значит нужно обновлять.

Нужны хорошие диски и внятный тюнинг параметров postgresql под эти диски. Тюнить необходимо настройки autovacuum - делать его куда более агрессивным, чтобы он успевал вычищать старые версии строк за вашими апдейтами. Затем настройки bgwriter увеличивать и настройки checkpoint, чтобы checkpoint происходил размазано по времени и не слишком часто.

Для хороших SSD можно использовать такие начальные настройки:

```
bgwriter_delay = 10ms
bgwriter_lru_maxpages = 1000
bgwriter_lru_multiplier = 10.0
checkpoint_timeout = 1h
max_wal_size = 48GB
min_wal_size = 4GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
autovacuum_max_workers = 10
autovacuum_naptime = 1s
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 50
autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 10
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.05
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.05
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 5ms
vacuum_cost_delay = 0
vacuum_cost_page_hit = 0
vacuum_cost_page_miss = 10
vacuum_cost_page_dirty = 10
vacuum_cost_limit = 100
vacuum_freeze_min_age = 5000000
vacuum_freeze_table_age = 15000000
```

И конечно, должно быть достаточно `shared_buffers` для работы.

Возможно для вашего профиля нагрузки будет очень хороша настройка `commit_delay` для фиксации группы транзакций одним `fsync`.

А, ещё обязательно настройте в кроне отстрел длительных транзакций. Под активным OLTP длительные транзакции будет сказываться крайне негативно на производительности базы, т.к. автовакуум не сможет выполнять свою работу. Задача в кроне что-то похожее на это:

```
* * * * * psql -d postgres -tx -c "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid),now(),now()-xact_start as duration,* from pg_stat_activity where (now() - pg_stat_activity.xact_start) > '10 min'::interval and usename NOT IN ('postgres', 'backup') and state<>'idle'" | grep -vE '^(|\(No rows\))$'
```

---

Касательно количества соединений - если у вас соединений к базе в 3 раза больше чем ядер на машине с базой - это плохо. Процессы postgresql будут драться между собой.

Необходим какой-то пул соединений. Мне так смутно помнится, что у этого nodejs пулер соединений есть родной.

Во всяком случае возможно поставить `pgbouncer` между приложением и базой, оптимально в режиме пула транзакций. Pgbouncer легко сможет держать тысячи открытых соединений с приложениями и предоставлять им лишь небольшое число соединений с базой на время выполнения непосредственно транзакций.

---

И отдельный вопрос - что именно делает ваше приложение. Судя по тому, что сначала что-то читается, а потом что-то пишется - это наверняка возможно занести в один запрос (возможно вызов хранимки) или по крайней мере в одну транзакцию, что кардинально улучшит производительность базы.

Comment: Node получает строку с внешнего устройства, парсит и записывает полученные данные в бд. В ответ на устройство отправляет тоже строку. Это если вкратце